# Boo Lists - Cast to (int)?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, mono, boo

I attempted to follow this tutorial which was originally written for UnityScript, but to use Boo instead:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Example-CreatingaBillboardPlane.html

Here's what I tried:

```
import UnityEngine

class CreateMesh (MonoBehaviour): 

    def Start ():
        meshFilter = GetComponent(MeshFilter)
        mesh = Mesh()
        mesh.vertices = [Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3(1, 0, 0), Vector3(0, 1, 0), Vector3(1, 1, 0)]
        mesh.triangles = [0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]
        mesh.normals = [-Vector3.forward, -Vector3.forward, -Vector3.forward, -Vector3.forward]
        meshFilter.mesh = mesh
    
    def Update ():
        pass
```

Unfortunately, each one of my list literals has caused problems:

> Cannot convert 'Boo.Lang.List' to '(UnityEngine.Vector3)'
>
> Cannot convert 'Boo.Lang.List' to '(int)'
>
> Cannot convert 'Boo.Lang.List' to '(UnityEngine.Vector3)'

This is a bit disappointing - I had expected that Boo would have been able to infer the type of my lists, since all the elements within are of the same type. In any event, I think that all that should be necessary is a cast statement of some sort. I've looked around at a few other Boo examples on Unity, but none of them seem to utilize lists like I want to.

I looked into it a bit and saw that I could cast to a list of type like this:

```
[...] as List[of type]
```

So I tried that like this:

```
mesh.triangles = [0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1] as List[of int]
```

But this still didn't work - it just changed my error message to:

> Cannot convert 'Boo.Lang.List[of int]' to '(int)'.

I have no idea what it means by `(int)` - I had assumed that was a `List` which consisted only of `int`s but it seems I must be wrong.

Comment: well, it appears a mod disagreed with you:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6151710.  I'd respond there, but, you know, it was deleted and all.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - That's okay. Reasonable people may disagree. It's why we have a human element of people manually checking flags rather than just having a script that automatically determines if something is a Link Only Answer or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key point: the Mesh class expects arrays, not lists. The two types are very similar, but not identical.

```
Type                 C#           Boo
-----------------------------------------------
List of integers     List<int>    List[of int]
Array of integers    int[]        (int)
Dictionary           ???          Dictionary[of key, value]
```

This line creates a list of ints:

```
mesh.triangles = [0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Versus an array of ints:

```
mesh.triangles = (0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Note we swap `[]` braces for `()` parens.

Comment: I am eternally in your debt - I must have tried 100 different ways to solve this in the past 10 hours. Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind extending your list to cover how I can specify the keys and values in a dictionary or hash in Boo?

Comment: I extended the list in your table to include how to make a Dictionary in Boo. You or someone else could add C# to it.